# Is there an automated way to split a JSON(B) column into multiple columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: json, postgresql, split, timescaledb

So I have a PostgreSQL (TimescaleDB) table that looks like this:

```
╔════════════════════════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║            tags            ║ time  ║ value ║
╠════════════════════════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ {"a": "test", "c": "test"} ║ 10:24 ║   123 ║
║ {"b": "test", "c": "test"} ║ 10:25 ║   110 ║
║ {"b": "test"}              ║ 10:26 ║   130 ║
╚════════════════════════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

And I would like to split the JSON(B) column into multiple columns like this:

```
╔════════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║   a    ║   b    ║   c    ║ time  ║ value ║
╠════════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║ "test" ║        ║ "test" ║ 10:24 ║   123 ║
║        ║ "test" ║ "test" ║ 10:25 ║   110 ║
║        ║ "test" ║        ║ 10:26 ║   130 ║
╚════════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

I looked into the [JSON Processing Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) and it seems that those require finding all the JSON(B) attributes and types. Is there a way to do this automatically?

Comment: No, there's never a way to dynamically create columns in a query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make this dynamic. The number (and types) of all columns of a query must be known to the database when parsing the statement, long before it's actually executed.

---

If you always have the same structure you can create a type:

```
create type tag_type as (a text, b text, c text);
```

and then use `jsonb_populate_record()`

```
select (jsonb_populate_record(null::tag_type, tags)).*, time, value
from the_table;
```

Comment: I would have liked the solution to be dynamic because the tags change dynamically. If this is not possible however then your answer seems to be the way to go.

Comment: there is no way to make this dynamic. The number (and types) of all columns of a query must be known to the database when parsing the statement, long before it's actually executed

Comment: Can you maybe add this to your answer at the top because this answers my question directly.